# Помогите перебрать массив с помощью конструкции if()

Tags: javascript, json

```
const inputDataArray = [
  { parentName: null, itemName: "programming" },
  { parentName: "mobile", itemName: "ios" },
  { parentName: "mobile", itemName: "android" },
  { parentName: "backend", itemName: "nodejs" },
  { parentName: "frontend", itemName: "angular" },
  { parentName: "frontend", itemName: "react" },
  { parentName: "programming", itemName: "web" },
  { parentName: "frontend", itemName: "vue" },
  { parentName: "backend", itemName: "nodejs" },
  { parentName: "web", itemName: "backend" },
  { parentName: "programming", itemName: "mobile" },
  { parentName: "web", itemName: "frontend" },
];
const getResult = (inputDataArray, parentName) => {
    let resultObj = {}
    for (let i = 0; i < inputDataArray.length; i++){
        if (inputDataArray[i].parentName === ??????) {
            resultObj[inputDataArray[i].??????] = ??????;
        }
    }
    return resultObj;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getResult(inputDataArray,null),null,4));
```

На выходе:

```
{
    "programming": {
        "web": {
            "backend": {
                "nodejs":{}
            },
            "frontend": {
                "angular": { },
                "react": { },
                "vue": { }
            }
        },
        "mobile": {
            "ios": { },
            "android":{}
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let inputDataArray = [
  { parentName: null, itemName: "programming" },
  { parentName: "mobile", itemName: "ios" },
  { parentName: "mobile", itemName: "android" },
  { parentName: "backend", itemName: "nodejs" },
  { parentName: "frontend", itemName: "angular" },
  { parentName: "frontend", itemName: "react" },
  { parentName: "programming", itemName: "web" },
  { parentName: "frontend", itemName: "vue" },
  { parentName: "backend", itemName: "nodejs" },
  { parentName: "web", itemName: "backend" },
  { parentName: "programming", itemName: "mobile" },
  { parentName: "web", itemName: "frontend" },
];
const getResult = (inputDataArray, parentName) => {
    let resultObj = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < inputDataArray.length; i++){
        if (inputDataArray[i].parentName === parentName) {
            resultObj[inputDataArray[i].itemName] = getResult(inputDataArray,inputDataArray[i].itemName);
        }
    }
    return resultObj;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getResult(inputDataArray,null),null,4));
```